# How to initialize multiple routers?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-routing

I have two resources in `Routers`: `Students` and `Colleges`.

```
class App.Routers.Colleges extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
   "index": 'index'
class App.Routers.Students extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
   'index': 'index'
   'new': 'newStudent'
```

How to initialise these two routes such that they work?

I have tried to initialize like the code below but it's not working.

```
window.App =
 Models: {}
 Collections: {}
 Views: {}
 Routers: {}
 initialize: ->
   new App.Routers.Students
   new App.Routers.Colleges
   Backbone.history.start()
 $(document).ready ->
   App.initialize()
```

When I try to run the above code, it's only showing me the data in `new App.Routers.Colleges` in both colleges and students div.

Answer (score 1):

Routes in routers are added to the global `Backbone.history` object. So any identical route overrides the precedent ones. Even non-identical routes may override a similar but more specific route if defined after.

When instantiating a new Router, its constructor calls [`_bindRoutes`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7da4ed73e7402baf614a50a6551d47ace68b5239/backbone.js#L1633-L1640) which parses routes from the last to the first so specific routes should be defined first and the more generic routes after, ending with any catch-all route.

Every URL needs to be unique, so you could namespace every router with a prefix:

```
class App.Routers.Colleges extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
   'colleges': 'index'
class App.Routers.Students extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
   'students/new': 'newStudent'
   'students': 'index'
```

Or you could use (or make your own) sub-router/controller.

- [Backbone.subroute](https://github.com/BackboneSubroute/backbone.subroute) (no longer maintained)
- [Backbone.controller](https://github.com/artyomtrityak/backbone.controller) (doesn't look like it handles similar routes, but it may help)